# org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot find class in classpath: com.facebook.qa.testcases.LoginPageTest

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot find class in classpath: com.facebook.qa.testcases.LoginPageTest
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:77)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:69)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:55)
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:575)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:766)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:356)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:38)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:152)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:233)
    at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:295)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:348)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeEverything(TestNG.java:995)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12.initialize(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:22)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:97)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Hi guys,

Can anyone help me to solve above `TestNG` exception?

ANSWER : I saw that this message was closed without answer. I had same issue and spent hours trying all available online solutions. Finally, I figured out myself that I had placed TestRunner (Driver script) in main package instead of test package of maven project. Once I moved it to test package, it worked like a charm ! Hope this helps to others.

Comment: I tried both still thorwing same exception Thank you

Comment: Show us your `testng.xml`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.facebook.qa.testcases.LoginPageTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

Comment: Check that you do really have the class `com.facebook.qa.testcases.LoginPageTest`

Comment: Yes com.facebook.qa.testcases is a package name and LoginPageTest is a class name

Comment: How do you run your tests?

Comment: Add more description to your question. paste your code and where are you getting the error. Also go through the link to understand how to ask a question [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">` in testng.xml file replace https with http
It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Clean your project and re-run again. `Project->clean`

or else

In testNG.xml ->configure as `<class name="Packagename.Classname"/>` . This issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the Java  Path for the JRE in Properties >> Java Built Path >> JRE System library

Comment: For answers to older questions, it's better to give more explanation. That way you can highlight why your answer is an improvement on the older answers.